# Numbering each output line in Python

Tags: python

python: read in a file and repeat every line twice
        number the output lines

Example:
Given this file:

```
Invictus

Out of the night that covers me
Black as the pit from pole to pole
I thank whatever gods there may be
For my unconquerable soul
```

Here is the output:

```
1 Invictus
1 Invictus
2
2
3 Out of the night that covers me
3 Out of the night that covers me
4 Black as the pit from pole to pole
4 Black as the pit from pole to pole
5 I thank whatever gods there may be
5 I thank whatever gods there may be
6 For my unconquerable soul
6 For my unconquerable soul
```

---

here's the code I have so far, I haven't been able to figure out the loop needed to put the double numbering at each line:

```
fileicareabout = open("ourownfile","r")
text = fileicareabout.readlines()
count = len(open("ourownfile").readlines(  ))
fileicareabout.close()
def linecount(ourownfile):
    count = 0
    for x in open("ourownfile"):
        count += 1
    return count

for words in text:
    print (str(linecount) + words) * 2
print
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying the numbering needs to increment while pasting each line twice? So it needs to be:
1 Invictus

2 Invictus

3

4

5 Out of the night that covers me

If so, your loop should look like this:

```
count = 0
for words in text:
      print(str(count) + words)
      count += 1
      print(str(count) + words)
      count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication operator (`*`) might be handy.

**Example:**

```
>>> '15 hello world\n' * 2
'15 hello world\n15 hello world\n'
```

**Following the same logic:**

```
counter = 1
with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        for line in input_file:
            output_file.write( '{} {}'.format(counter, line) * 2  )
            counter += 1
```

**input.txt:**

```
hello
world
my
name
is
Sait
```

**output.txt:**

```
1 hello
1 hello
2 world
2 world
3 my
3 my
4 name
4 name
5 is
5 is
6 Sait
6 Sait
```

Comment: that seems reasonable how should i add it to the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate to keep count of your line number:

```
with open("ourownfile") as f:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        print "{} {}".format(line_no, line)*2,
```

Or using the newer print function (required for python 3):

```
from __future__ import print_function

with open("ourownfile") as f:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        print("{} {}".format(line_no, line)*2, end='')
```

To get your exact output it looks like you skip the first line:

```
with open("ourownfile") as f:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(f):
        if line_no == 0:
            continue
        print("{} {}".format(line_no, line)*2, end='')
```